# Scroll is working with Listbox widget but not working with text widget in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, scroll

I have taken two frames for the Listbox and Text widgets respectively. The scroll is working fine with Listbox but not working with the Text widget. I am using MVS as my IDE. Could anyone explain the reason for the nonfunctioning of the scroll with the Text widget or what is wrong with my code? Thanks

```py
from tkinter import *
from turtle import right
# from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("GUI Course")
root.geometry("800x500+250+50") 
#root.config(bg="#262626")

#----------------Scroll with Listbox-------------
frame1 = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=RIDGE)
frame1.place(x=100,y=100,height=200,width=200)

scrolly1 = Scrollbar(frame1, orient=VERTICAL)
scrolly1.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

data = Listbox(frame1, font=("time new roman",20), justify=CENTER, yscrollcommand=scrolly1.set)
data.pack()

scrolly1.config(command=data.yview)

for i in range(0,101):
    data.insert(i, "Data: "+str(i))

#-----------------Scroll with text-----------
frame2 = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=RIDGE)
frame2.place(x=400,y=100,height=200,width=200)

scrolly2 = Scrollbar(frame2, orient=VERTICAL)
scrolly2.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

text = Text(frame2, font=("times new roman",10), yscrollcommand=scrolly2.set)
text.pack()

scrolly2.config(command=text.yview)

for i in range(0,101):
    flt = 0.0
    text.insert(flt,"Python "+str(i))
    flt += 1


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you try running using `cmd`. 'cause this is working fine for me.

Comment: The scrollbar for the text widget seems to work just fine for me  when I run this code.

Comment: The issue can be reproduced in my Windows 7 running Python 3.8.13 and it can be fixed by calling `root.update()` before inserting text into the text box or performing the insertion after the window is shown. Also it can be fixed if "\n" is added in each iteration.

Comment: Thank you. It worked fine for vertical scroll on the right of the Text widget using the root.update(), can we use it for horizontal scroll and what would be the changes required in that case, Regards